# Calling class method within class error

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

```
class String(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.text)

    def reverse(self):
        return self.text[::-1]

    def isPalindrome(self):
        return (self.reverse(self.text) == self.text)


def main():
    string = String(input("Write a String: "))

    if(string.isPalindrome()):
        print("The string {{}} IS a Palindrome".format(string))
    else:
        print("The string {{}} is NOT Palindrome".format(string))
```

I have this classe that represents a `String` and i want to check is a object is a palindrome by calling the method `isPalindrome`. But when i call the `string.isPalindrome` i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "palindrome.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "palindrome.py", line 17, in main
    if(string.isPalindrome()):
  File "palindrome.py", line 12, in isPalindrome
    return (self.reverse(self.text) == self.text)
TypeError: reverse() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: The exception makes it very clear where you error is: `TypeError: reverse() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: `self` is an implied argument whenever you call a method from an instance.  For instance, in `obj.reverse()`, `obj` automatically becomes `self` within the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```
return (self.reverse(self.text) == self.text)
```

change it for this:

```
return (self.reverse() == self.text)
```

`self` can be really confusing, here is a really good [article](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/) to understand how it works. Just so you understand, look at `reverse()` definition:

```
def reverse(self):
    return self.text[::-1]
```

As you can see, `self.text` is already assigned. No need to pass it to the function when calling it.

Comment: no problem, please accept this answer if it was helpful.

Comment: i was waiting the time limit :)

Comment: @ViniciusBarbosa No problem !